# How do I go from embedded Jetty web project to standalone server?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, jetty

I build restful web service using maven on Eclipse and test with embedded server. All of this succeeds, now I want to deploy on a standalone Jetty server.

I was able to get Jetty running but when I go http://host:8080/my-war-file/ I see only directory with META-INF and WEB-INF, which Jetty thinks are both empty.

I do not believe there is a problem with my war file

```
/my-war-file
    /META-INF
    /WEB-INF
        /classes
        /lib
        web.xml
```

How can I access resource classes through browser running Jetty standalone?

Comment: Please include how you setup/configured your jetty standalone, along with how you "deployed" your web application to your `${jetty.base}`

Comment: I built the war file using maven and moved the war file under the web app folder. The errors I'm getting are SEVERE: Method annotated with GET resource is not recognized as a valid resource method for all of my resource methods.

Comment: that is not an error produced by Jetty, that's probably coming from a 3rd party library.  (Just guessing, but its probably a REST/JaxRs library)